# LWP::Simple get not working via URL

Tags: perl, lwp

I have a very simple test perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use LWP::Simple;

my ($cgireq) = new CGI;
print $cgireq->header();
$info = get("http://www.vismetrics.com/");
print 'direct result is ' . $info;
```

when I log onto the server and run this from the command line (linux, perl 5.8.8) it works fine.  But when I run it via apache (on the same server) using a URL to refer to the perl script, it doesn't work.  $info is blank.

Any ideas as to what could be different when running via apache?  thanks!

Andrew

Comment: Did you look in your apache error logs? Do you need to output HTTP headers?

Comment: You'll get more feedback from it's not-over-simplified brother, LWP::UserAgent

Comment: One possibility is that selinux is preventing outgoing connections from your web server children.

Comment: Yep, should have noted that.  I looked in the logs and no errors, just response code 200 when I hit that script.  Also, in my httpd.conf file I just have "AddHandler cgi-script .pl
".   There is no reference to mod_perl.  don't know if that helps. thanks!

Comment: Bloody selinux!  Tripped me up again. That was the solution.     "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1" did the trick.  thanks ikegami.  I would be happy to vote for you if you enter your suggestion as an answer.  I don't see  away to vote up comments?

Comment: Go ahead and answer the question yourself. You've found the command.

Answer (score 0):

Bloody selinux! Tripped me up again. That was the solution. 
"setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1" did the trick:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/how-do-i-configure-selinux-to-allow-outbound-connections-from-a-cgi-script

thanks ikegami!